# Односвязные списки

Tags: c++, список

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

struct list
{
    string oldState, symbol, newState;
    list *next;
};

list *field = NULL;
list *start = NULL;

void addList(string oldState, string value, string newState)
{
    if (field == NULL)
    {
        field->oldState = oldState;
        field->symbol = value;
        field->newState = newState;
        field->next = NULL;
        //start = field;
    }
    else
    {
        while (field)
        {
            field = field->next;
            if (!field)
                field = new list;
        }
        field->oldState = oldState;
        field->symbol = value;
        field->newState = newState;
        field->next = NULL;
    }
}

int main()
{
    addList("1", "2", "3");
    cout << field->oldState << field->symbol << field->newState;
    return 0;
}
```

Я видимо совсем запутался с этими указателями, или чего-то не понимаю. Объясните, почему это не работает?

Comment: @Beraliv, часто хорошей идеей работы с односвязными списками является использование 2-х указателей в заголовке списка. На первый и на последний элементы списка. 

В этом случае для добавления нового элемента в конец списка не нужно перебирать их все.

Если же порядок не столь важен, то можно использовать "стек". В этом случае новый элемент всегда добавляется в начало (становится первым) в списке. Тогда для предсавления списка достаточно одного указателя на  первый элемента.

В обоих случаях для инициализации списка достаточно обнулить указатель на голову.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я вот так исправил

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct mylist // здесь заменил имя типа. просто list уже используется в stl.
{
    string oldState, symbol, newState;
    mylist *next;
};

mylist *start = NULL;

void addList(string oldState, string value, string newState)
{
    if (start == NULL)
    {
        start = new mylist(); // нужно создать элемент. Иначе ошибка.
        start->oldState = oldState;
        start->symbol = value;
        start->newState = newState;
        start->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        mylist * field = start;
        while (field->next != NULL)
        {
            field = field->next;
        };
        field->next = new mylist();
        field = field->next;
        field->oldState = oldState;
        field->symbol = value;
        field->newState = newState;
        field->next = NULL;
    }
}

int main()
{
    addList("1", "2", "3");
    cout << start->oldState << start->symbol << start->newState;
    return 0;
}
```

Создание нового элемента можно вынести в отдельную функцию.

Comment: Огромное спасибо